# Error when manipulating dataframe with columns of type string with Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the dataframe:

[image]

And I would like to obtain using Pivot Table or an alternative function this result:

[image]

I am trying to transform the rows of the Custom Field column into Columns, with the Pivot Table function of Pandas, and I get an error:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
"Custom Field": ["CF1", "CF2", "CF3"],
"id": ["RSA", "RSB", "RSC"],
"Name": ["Wilson", "Junior", "Otavio"]
}

### create the dataframe ###
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

df2 = df.pivot_table(columns=['Custom Field'], index=['Name'])
print(df2)
```

[image]

I suspect it is because I am working with Strings.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot), not [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table). The latter does aggregation on possibly repeating values whereas the former is just a rearrangement of the values and fails for duplicate values.

```
df.pivot(columns=['Custom Field'], index=['Name'])
```

---

Update as per comment: if there are multiple values per cell, you need to use `privot_table` and specify an appropriate aggregate function, e.g. concatenate the string values. You can also specify a fill value for empty cells (instead of `NaN`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Custom Field": ["CF1", "CF2", "CF3", "CF1"],
                   "id": ["RSA", "RSB", "RSC", "RSD"],
                   "Name": ["Wilson", "Junior", "Otavio", "Wilson"]})

df.pivot_table(columns=['Custom Field'], index=['Name'], aggfunc=','.join, fill_value='-')
```

```
                    id          
Custom Field       CF1  CF2  CF3
Name                            
Junior               -  RSB    -
Otavio               -    -  RSC
Wilson         RSA,RSD    -    -
```

Comment: I have a question: if the Name column has duplicate values, what would be the solution?

Comment: @JuniorP please see my updated answer for this case.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much for the additional information!